# How do I access an existing map in Nokia Maps API if the map is out of scope?

Tags: javascript, here-api

I have an instance of Nokia maps that I have to use in a few different places around a web app. I thought it would make sense to use the single map and move it around on the page when needed, so I wouldn't have to create a new instance every time.

The object is instantiated with:

```
var map = new nokia.maps.map.Display(mapContainer, [options])
```

Now I've got a map object, but due to the (custom) framework that I'm using, I can't get to that object from a function because it's out of scope. Is there a way to access that object?

I tried accessing it like this:

```
var map = nokia.maps.map.Display(mapContainer);
```

But that didn't seem to produce results.

I also tried just creating a new map in the same container (thinking it may overwrite or do something clever) but it just created a second map, which didn't help. I also tried making the map a jQuery variable ($.map = new nokia.maps.map.Display(mapContainer [options]), but Nokia's map API didn't like that at all.

I'm going through the documentation but I can't seem to find anything. Unless I can figure out a way to store the object and get back to it, I'm going to have to instantiate a new map every time a user performs certain actions, which is less than ideal.

Comment: I wan't able to figure this out this, so I ended up using the REST API and creating static images instead of a Javascript map.

Answer (score 0):

Product no longer exits. thanks for connecting with us. please refer https://developer.here.com/ for our new APIs.